# Eliminate waiting time on Confirmation dialogue when server response is required

Tags: php, android, android-studio

I have an Android app that sends data to a MySQL server. My problem is whenever I hit the confirmation it takes a while to get a response from the server. Meanwhile, if I keep pressing the confirmation button the server keeps getting same data over & over. Could anyone please suggest anything to prevent it?

Comment: After the first press, just disable the confirmation until you get a response.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The confirmation dialogue only disappears after the response from the server. Until then, it keeps waiting on the screen. & Meanwhile on every click it sends data to server.

Comment: If it is a native confirmation box, then you should be able to close the confirmation box before making the actual request. So, click "confirm", close the confirmation box, show a loader while making the request, hide the loader when you get a response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see exactly what your doing, so I will just tell you how I would do it, first create a onClick method, then inside that set btn.setEnabled(false); + show a message stating the update in progress, then below that call a timer type method or a event listener type method, that runs for a set time limit while monitoring the update event, and then re-enable the button when the listener event method signals it has finished or re-enable the button after a certain time limit set in listener event method and give them a message saying the update didn't happen because of some type of error and they should try to complete their task again at a later time...

Comment: Let me try. I will post a feedback on this again.